# Early Drivers License Issued For Child With Disabled Parents

Tags: driving

I am 16 years old,
I got my drivers permit February 3rd, 2017 and my 6 months ends August 3rd, 2017,
I live in South Carolina, United States.

**Question:**
My father says I can get my drivers license early (before August 3rd) because he is legally disabled. He states this because he thinks there is a law that if I pass the driving test even though i'm in the 6 months of the drivers permit so I can drive him around. I could wait until August 3rd but my brother and his wife are coming to South Carolina to visit for the summer (next week) and I would love to surprise them with me getting my driver's license.
What my father is stating about me being able to get my drivers license early, is it true? I am too young to know much about the law (or care to study it). So I am here asking for your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described by [the private, independent website DMV.com](https://www.dmv.com/sc/south-carolina/learners-permit), on its page for South Carolina driving license, both the provisional and the special restricted driving license require that applicants aged between 15 and 16 or between 16 and 17, respectively,

> must have held a beginner's driving permit for at least 180 days. The following requirements must also be fulfilled:
>
> - Complete a driver's ed course.
> - Have satisfactory school attendance.
> - Accumulate at least 30 hours of daytime driving and at least 10 hours of nighttime driving experience.

There is no exception noted for a person to skip the 180 days requirement on the basis of providing transport for a disabled family member.