# Age you have to be to drive with a disabled parent

Tags: driving, minor, age

I was in a car accident 9 years ago. My spine was fused twice and I know I am permanently disabled. I have 2 kids, one is 12 years old and another is 14.

Can the oldest child get an early driver's license? If so, what age can he do so?

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Early Drivers License Issued For Child With Disabled Parents](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/20067/2618)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to law.SE! Please note that most questions need you to state a country/jurisdiction, as law is different in different places. Are you asking about the USA? Which state?

Answer (score 14):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Possibly, depends on the state. [Texas law](https://codes.findlaw.com/tx/transportation-code/transp-sect-521-223/) allows early drivers licenses under this circumstance, though there is an age requirement (15 years). California allows such a license for 14 years olds. OTOH, Washington state does not have such hardship exceptions to the general age rule. Also, in various states (e.g. [Alaska](https://doa.alaska.gov/dmv/akol/permit.htm)), a person 14 years old can obtain a learner's permit, which would allow them to do the driving is there is a licensed driver at least 21 years old with at least one year of driving experience in the passenger's seat.

Comment: Would it be possible that someone gets a license that only allows them to drive when accompanied by an adult with a driving license? (Also assuming that OP who was in a car accident may have a driving license. And assuming your driving license is valid for a long time, or can be extended by someone who is not physically capable of driving. )

Comment: That's the learner's permit option.

Comment: @user6726 that was my initial reaction, but IIRC there's potentially an important difference.  Most states don't allow people with learners permits to drive beyond their borders.  If living in a small state, or close to a state line, this could be a significant problem.  A junior license of the type gnasher789 was speculating about might not have that limitation.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight states don't have any say over whether people can drive in other states.  The reason someone with a learner's permit can'r drive in another state is that the other state doesn't allow it.  But many states _do_ allow it.